# Getting decimal values from window width and height

Tags: javascript

just a quick question. I need to get decimal values for a little project of mine. The main idea is to do Window.height/10.

That's the value I need but I want the outcome to be something like:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

It also has to be relative since its meant to be for differed window sizes. I've tried things with math.round but that doesn't give me decimal values.

Someone has an idea?

It's in Javascript.

Comment: Which Platform? Which language? What Technology?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! its in javascript

Comment: `alert(parseInt(window.innerWidth)+'X'+parseInt(window.innerHeight));` May Help you !

Comment: @VedantTerkar How?

Comment: @ashleedawg, Hope you've seen my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205421/2010838

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function wXh(){
var wid=parseInt(window.innerWidth);
var hgh=parseInt(window.innerHeight);
var hby10=parseInt(hgh/10);
alert(hby10);
alert("Original Dimensions Were :- "+wid+"X"+hgh);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="wXh();">
</body>
</html>
```

Will Alert The Value of your Browser window's height divided by 10 as Integer. and then will alert original dimensions too.

**--EDIT 1--**

According to your comment,
Changed Answer is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function wXh(){
var wid=parseInt(window.innerWidth);
var hgh=parseInt(window.innerHeight);
var hby10=parseInt(hgh/10);
var MSB=parseInt(hby10/10);
MSB=MSB>0?MSB*10:hby10;
alert(MSB);
alert("Original Dimensions Were :- "+wid+"X"+hgh);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="wXh();">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks! is it also possible to make the value 90 or 100?

Comment: @Tbmluijten Changed The answer! Have a look at that

Comment: I'm glad that i could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you can round up the window's height to the nearest ten with the following.

```
var windowHeight = Math.ceil( ( window.innerHeight + 1 ) / 10 ) * 10;
```

Comment: I'm creating a snake game in which a user can go to the far right of the level and then will be "teleported" to the left of the window. Since the game is working on decimals (cell width = 10 ) the problem is when I go from right to the left the value is not a decimal anymore. Because my width is 1436/10 = 143.6 and has to become something like 140 or 150. It's hard for me to explain I'm very new to javacript and programming. But still thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean?

Is it Java/C#/C++?

anyways, divide by float or double.

Ex: float ratio = width / 10.0f;

Comment: It's javascript. I've adjusted the post. Sorry for the confusion :D